# C# Forms - remove column header in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms

(sorry for links, not allowed to post images)

I have a 10x10 datagridview with images (black squares are images) in each grid.

I have a weird row at the top with a null image icon at the top.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNnbr.png

I have made inivisble all column and row headers in the properties

https://i.stack.imgur.com/R84v3.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCzHn.png

10 Columns, all the same settings as the one showed:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ghxdj.png

The code to add the images in each row.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xd12A.png

Comment: Instead of posting code or error messages as images or links, please copy/paste or type the actual code or error message directly into the post as text (within a code block). [Code in images cannot be copied to reproduce the issue, and error messages in images cannot be searched](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/208273). Links to code may become invalid if the linked site changes.  If your code is too long to fit in the post, we have tips on [how to create a minimal, reproducible example](//stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clear the grid before adding rows:

```
this.gridMachines.Rows.Clear();
```